# how to migrate old version's gems to new version's gems with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I just updated my local ruby version from `2.1.3` to `2.2.2` by `rbenv` in Mac.

Normally after updating I install a gem when I notice that is missing.
Is there a easy way to "migrate" old gems to new version ruby environment?

Of course I'm using `Gemfile` in projects, but I don't know how to handle gem list outside project directories.

Comment: If you run `gem list` in your Ruby 2.1.3 environment, that can get you a list of all the gems you installed and which versions.  Then you could write a little program that converts that into a set of "gem install" commands that install those same versions.  That might be a lot of work compared to running "bundle" in each of your projects when you need to.

Comment: If you install using ``bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`` for example. Then you would initially have a ruby folder named 2.1.0 under your vendor/bundle directory. You could change the name to 2.2.0 but you are probably going to run into all sorts of conflicts. There's a reason why the folders are separated based on the ruby version...

Comment: @DavidGrayson It's little bit cumbersome, I'll stick my old style. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MariusPop If it's so cumbersome I'll  just install when I need gems each time. Thanks your advice!